# Is there a way to add html attributes to an existing html element with Emmet?

Tags: html, workflow, emmet

I've been looking around and I can not find an answer to this.

Suppose I put the cursor right between the number 2 and the greater than sign in the following h2's opening tag.

```
<h2>Hello world!</h2>
```

And then I type `.text-uppercase` which gives me:

```
 <h2.text-uppercase>Hello world!</h2>
```

After which I expand the abbriviation and I get

```
 <h2 class="text-uppercase">Hello world!</h2>
```

---

Is there a way to achieve this by another method?

Comment: I think it's a little unclear what you are specifically asking. Are you asking whether the `h2` can be equivalently styled using another method?

Comment: I don't think I can make it more clear. Have you used Emmet?

Comment: *I* think you could make it more clear; I don't understand what you're asking either. Achieve what? Adding a class? What other kind of "method" are you talking about? Without typing? Via a command? Add arbitrary attributes (which isn't what Emmett does, it has shortcuts for ID and classes, it doesn't have shortcuts for every attribute on every tag).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this works](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/commit/15bb514f82e72bb4752e546814aeaedf132dbb3a) in your editor, in my personal VS Code installation, its not working, the action is `Update Tag`

Answer (score -1):

I think you want this:

```
var h2 = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");
h2.classList.add('text-uppercase');
```

Now you can do it onClick or using some other trigger.